# Uncaught Error: Class 'SMTP' not found, usando PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Quiero enviar un correo con la clase `PHPMailer` pero me da error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SMTP' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\clientes\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php:1466 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\clientes\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php(1549): PHPMailer->getSMTPInstance() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\clientes\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php(1486): PHPMailer->smtpConnect(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\clientes\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php(1323): PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Fri, 10 M...', 'This is a multi...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\clientes\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php(1203): PHPMailer->postSend() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\clientes\federal\administrador\correo.php(22): PHPMailer->send() #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\clientes\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php on line 1466

Y mi código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
require("../../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new  PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "localhost";

// SMTP a utilizar. Por ej. smtp.elserver.com
$mail->Username = "root"; // Correo completo a utilizar
$mail->Password = ""; // Contraseña
$mail->Port = 25; // Puerto a utilizar
$mail->From = "info@elserver.com"; // Desde donde enviamos (Para mostrar)
$mail->FromName = "ELSERVER.COM";
$mail->AddAddress("correo"); // Esta es la dirección a donde enviamos
$mail->AddCC("cuenta@dominio.com"); // Copia
$mail->AddBCC("cuenta@dominio.com"); // Copia oculta
$mail->IsHTML(true); // El correo se envía como HTML
$mail->Subject = "Titulo"; // Este es el titulo del email.

$body = 'Hola mundo. Esta es la primer línea<br />';
$body .= "Acá continuo el<strong>mensaje</strong>";
$mail->Body = $body; // Mensaje a enviar
$mail->AltBody = "Hola mundo. Esta es la primer línean Acá continuo el mensaje"; // Texto sin html
$mail->AddAttachment("imagenes/imagen.jpg", "imagen.jpg");
$exito = $mail->Send(); // Envía el correo.

if($exito){
  echo "El correo fue enviado correctamente.";
} else {
  echo "Hubo un inconveniente. Contacta a un administrador.";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te esta faltando incluir el archivo [`class.smtp.php`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#minimal-installation)

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
require("../../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
require("../../phpmailer/class.smtp.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

El tema es que no debes cargar la clase directamente si no el autocarga.

elimina esta línea.

```
require("../../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
```

Debes poner esta

```
require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

suerte

Answer (score 0):

Ahora tengo este error

```
2017-03-10 19:25:56 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP r50sm4618141otd.20 - gsmtp 2017-03-10 19:25:56   CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2017-03-10 19:25:56    SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [201.122.207.46] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 2017-03-10 19:25:56    CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2017-03-10 19:25:56    SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 2017-03-10 19:25:56  CLIENT -> SERVER: cHJheGVkZXMxMzE0QGdtYWlsLmNvbQ== 2017-03-10 19:25:56  SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 2017-03-10 19:25:56  CLIENT -> SERVER: X3ByYXhlZGVzMTIz 2017-03-10 19:25:56  SERVER -> CLIENT: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 r50sm4618141otd.20 - gsmtp 2017-03-10 19:25:56  SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 r50sm4618141otd.20 - gsmtp 2017-03-10 19:25:56   SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 2017-03-10 19:25:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2017-03-10 19:25:56  SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection r50sm4618141otd.20 - gsmtp 2017-03-10 19:25:56   SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Error al enviar: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

pero me acabo de dar cuenta que gmail bloqueo el acceso alguien sabe como permitir el acceso

Answer (score -1):

Revisa que tengas cargada la librería de `smtp mailer`, el error es que no encuentra la librería.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y para futuras respuestas, ten en cuenta [cómo debes responder una pregunta en Stack Overflow](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - esto es para mejorar la calidad de tus publicaciones en este sitio-.